# reduce the width of the "subscribe" button

Tags: html, css

we have  "subscribe" button as here,

[image]

but we want to reduce the extra width and want to display as like in this

[image]

we are using same code in both

```
.footer .block-subscribe .actions {
    float: left;
    width: 34.375%;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer .block-subscribe .input-box {
    float: left;
    width: 65.625%;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code and adjust padding as you want. Hope this will help you. Thanks.

```css
   button
{ background: #ff7704;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 50px;}
```

```html
<button type="submit" title="Subscribe" class="button"><span><span>Subscribe</span></span></button>
```

Comment: its not reducing 41px  after  `padding: 7px 41px;` measn if i reduce below  41, its not working.

Comment: you mean padding not adding after 7px 41px?

Comment: yes, wheni tried to decrease from 41 to 40, 39, 38 so on, its not reducing. please check

Comment: so there is some width is applied try to find it. and remove it.

Comment: i tried lot, but nothing worked for me. if you get free time please check once.

Comment: there is extra space there in left and right for "subscribe" text. i want to remove those extra space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114519/discussion-between-sagar-kodte-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Answer (score 1):

You have give the padding left and right 
    .button {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    }

Comment: is i need to remove this or add this : `padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;` also cany you please help me to find out line number of this code

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that in http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/skin/frontend/rwd/Stylebaby/css/styles.css, on line 300, you have specified the button property:

```
min-width: 140px
```

This is what's causing your button width to be expanded. There are many ways you could choose to remove/override this property, so I'll leave that implementation detail up to you.